# A strange behavior of SSL in using the symmetric encryption key?

Tags: ssl, encryption

I've used wireshark to watch several SSL3.0 traffic and decrypt the messages transferred between client & server.

And what I've just found is very strange :

AFAIK, the encryption-key, MAC and encryption algorithm used in calculating client-Finished and application-data sent by client are exactly the same.

But, when I use the same client-write-key used to encrypt client-finished (Derived from MasterSecret) to encrypt application data, I get the different result from what the client (firefox) calculated.

The odd behavior also happened with server: I can use server-write-key (derive from MasterSecret) to decrypt successfully the "server-finished" message, but failed to decrypt any other encrypted message from server.

So, can you please tell me what happened to the client-write-key & server-write-key ?
Did both client and server changed their write-key after "finished" message sent?

PS: I forced client (Firefox) to use SSL V3.0, cipherSuite = TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming.

Comment: @EugeneMayevski'EldoSCorp: Thanks. Can you please clarify your opinion ?

Comment: StackOveflow site is for programming-related questions only (it's not about generic computing or security).

Comment: I think if you read my question once again, with SSL knowledge, you'd realize that it's not that off-topic. I'm implementing SSL myself, and stucked in this step. I think it's not far different from the question "what's new in jQuery 1.9 method 'prop' ?". Hope you can change your argument.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found out the answer myself : the function RC4 I've used didn't save the cipher state, while SSL stream cipher required that. I've used a RC4 class and problem resolved!